# error when trying to use express in a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, stripe-payments

I've been trying to implement a paymentCtrl to handle the Stripe payments but am unable to get the express to work. When i execute this code i get the following error below. I'm quite new to this and would like to understand why i get this error.

error:

> Unknown provider: appProvider <- app <- paymentCtrl

app.js:

```
angular.module('userApp', ['appRoutes', 'userControllers', 'userServices', 'ngAnimate', 'mainController', 'authServices', 'managementController', 'paymentController'])

.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptors');
});
```

payment.html:

```
<div>

<form action="/charge" method="post">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
    class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_..."
    data-amount="3000"
    data-name="walla"
    data-description="this is not a dog"
    data-locale="auto"
    data-currency="gbp"
  ></script>


  </script>
</form>

</div>
```

paymentCtrl:

```
angular.module('paymentController', [])

.controller('paymentCtrl', function(app, passport) {

  app.post('/charge', function(req, res){

  });


});
```

server.js:

```
var express = require('express'); // ExperssJS Framework
var app = express(); // Invoke express to variable for use in application
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // Set default port or assign a port in enviornment
var morgan = require('morgan'); // Import Morgan Package
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); // HTTP request logger middleware for Node.js
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // Node.js body parsing middleware. Parses incoming request bodies in a middleware before your handlers, available under req.body.
var router = express.Router(); // Invoke the Express Router
var appRoutes = require('./app/routes/api')(router); // Import the application end points/API
var path = require('path'); // Import path module
var passport = require('passport'); // Express-compatible authentication middleware for Node.js.
var social = require('./app/passport/passport')(app, passport); // Import passport.js End Points/API
var stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_...');

app.use(morgan('dev')); // Morgan Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Body-parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // For parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // Allow front end to access public folder
app.use('/api', appRoutes); // Assign name to end points (e.g., '/api/management/', '/api/users' ,etc. )

//
// <---------- REPLACE WITH YOUR MONGOOSE CONFIGURATION ---------->
//
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/tutorial', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Not connected to the database: ' + err);
  } else {
    console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB');
  }
});

// Set Application Static Layout
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/app/views/index.html')); // Set index.html as layout
});

// Start Server
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Running the server on port ' + port); // Listen on configured port
});
```

Comment: You are getting an angular error I think. can you update your whole HTML code with the JS code. There's a problem with you controller in angular

Comment: Hmmm i'm not sure i understand what you mean by "update your whole HTML with the JS code"

Comment: Because your *payment.html* is missing the `ng-controller`.

Answer (score 0):

Your angular controller should be injected with `$http` module, app is undefined  in your client side code as client side would not inherit code from your server.

`$http` module contains `.post` method along side numerous other methods such as `.get .put .delete` etc.

```
angular.module('paymentController', [])

.controller('paymentCtrl', function(app, passport, $http) {

  $http.post('/charge', {}, function(req, res){

  });

});
```

The second parameters in the $http.post (`{}`) is the data you want to transmit to your controller.

Lastly, you need a server method which will retrieve the POST request.

```
app.post('/charge', function(req, res) {
    // Your server endpoint for /charge POST action
    // req.body contains passed data.
});
```

As you're trying to send data using Angular to your server, you'll need to bind the form data to your model, and remove the form or listen to form submit event and make a POST request yourself the way you want to.

As you have not included the whole HTML document, it is hard to see if there are any other errors included, such as missing `ng-controller` declaration in your document as comments stated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you followed [this Stripe tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/express) so all you need to do is:

The code you've written in **paymentCtrl** should be copied into server.js before `app.listen`

```
// Set Application Static Layout
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/app/views/index.html')); // Set index.html as layout
});

app.post('/charge', function(req, res){}); 


// Start Server
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Running the server on port ' + port); // Listen on configured port
});
```

> Unknown provider: appProvider <- app <- paymentCtrl

This means that `app` variable you are trying to inject does not exist in your client side code.